# attempted to leave type `platform::platform::x11::util::input::PointerState<'_>` uninitialized, which is invalid

Tags: rust

Следуя туториалу по amethyst, я написал следующий код:

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "amethyst"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = []
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.amethyst]
version = "0.15"
features = ["vulkan"]
```

config/display.ron

```
(
    title: "Pong!",
    dimensions: Some((500, 500)),
)
```

src/main.rs

```
use amethyst::{
    prelude::*,
    renderer::{
        plugins::{RenderFlat2D, RenderToWindow},
        types::DefaultBackend,
        RenderingBundle,
    },
    utils::application_root_dir,
};

pub struct Pong;
impl SimpleState for Pong {}

fn main() -> amethyst::Result<()> {
    amethyst::start_logger(Default::default());

    let app_root = application_root_dir()?;
    let display_config_path = app_root.join("config/display.ron");

    let game_data = GameDataBuilder::default().with_bundle(
        RenderingBundle::<DefaultBackend>::new()
            .with_plugin(
                RenderToWindow::from_config_path(display_config_path)?
                    .with_clear([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]),
            )
            .with_plugin(RenderFlat2D::default()),
    )?;

    let assets_dir = app_root.join("assets");

    let mut game = Application::new(assets_dir, Pong, game_data)?;
    game.run();
    Ok(())
}
```

После сборки и запуска программы, при наведении курсора на окно игры, выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.65s
warning: the following packages contain code that will be rejected by a future version of Rust: syn v0.14.9
note: to see what the problems were, use the option `--future-incompat-report`, or run `cargo report future-incompatibilities --id 32`
     Running `target/debug/amethyst`
[INFO][amethyst::app] Initializing Amethyst...
[INFO][amethyst::app] Version: 0.15.3
[INFO][amethyst::app] Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[INFO][amethyst::app] Amethyst git commit: UNKNOWN
[INFO][amethyst::app] Rustc version: 1.70.0-nightly Nightly
[INFO][amethyst::app] Rustc git commit: 0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd
[INFO][winit::platform::platform::x11::window] Guessed window DPI factor: 1
[WARN][gfx_backend_vulkan] Unable to find layer: VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation
[WARN][rendy_factory::factory] Slow safety checks are enabled! Disable them in production by enabling the 'no-slow-safety-checks' feature!
[INFO][rendy_util::wrap] Slow safety checks are enabled! You can disable them in production by enabling the 'no-slow-safety-checks' feature!
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `platform::platform::x11::util::input::PointerState<'_>` uninitialized, which is invalid', library/core/src/panicking.rs:126:5
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x55cb94b0f5ba - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::hb21916495ea4ce30
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
   1:     0x55cb94b0f5ba - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h87a4c2385889b628
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:     0x55cb94b0f5ba - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h476b694e734e3ab5
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:65:5
   3:     0x55cb94b0f5ba - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::hc5463142269052a4
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:44:22
   4:     0x55cb94b32dbf - core::fmt::write::hed237339d9ede273
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1254:17
   5:     0x55cb94b0c5f5 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h312c8af7134d7818
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1698:15
   6:     0x55cb94b0f385 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h38670e18f8a7498a
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47:5
   7:     0x55cb94b0f385 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::had5fdd69aa83ded4
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:34:9
   8:     0x55cb94b10a2e - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h0bea23f3763688e2
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:269:22
   9:     0x55cb94b107d5 - std::panicking::default_hook::hae8f5255ac8767ce
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:288:9
  10:     0x55cb94b10f8e - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h935021f4a6149bb9
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:690:13
  11:     0x55cb94b10e42 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::hd801f012dedd1e35
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:579:13
  12:     0x55cb94b0fa26 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h9dbe89a35d9d19c0
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:150:18
  13:     0x55cb94b10be2 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:577:5
  14:     0x55cb93e1ee33 - core::panicking::panic_nounwind_fmt::hbdf0544565a90308
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/panicking.rs:96:14
  15:     0x55cb93e1eee1 - core::panicking::panic_nounwind::h3ef35b8cfb34ea5f
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/panicking.rs:126:5
  16:     0x55cb9451014a - core::mem::uninitialized::hf58d1733ae4ba84f
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs:685:9
  17:     0x55cb9451014a - winit::platform::platform::x11::util::input::<impl winit::platform::platform::x11::xdisplay::XConnection>::query_pointer::hc9b34a3dc0e73c80
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.19.5/src/platform/linux/x11/util/input.rs:94:51
  18:     0x55cb943599f0 - winit::platform::platform::x11::EventsLoop::process_event::hc8ebf31947b08a33
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.19.5/src/platform/linux/x11/mod.rs:956:45
  19:     0x55cb94354e03 - winit::platform::platform::x11::EventsLoop::poll_events::hb6066bd29d5c4cb2
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.19.5/src/platform/linux/x11/mod.rs:270:13
  20:     0x55cb94344534 - winit::platform::platform::EventsLoop::poll_events::h9a1f8cf99f7f98d3
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.19.5/src/platform/linux/mod.rs:522:44
  21:     0x55cb94343fe4 - winit::EventsLoop::poll_events::h745db394e63bcb2c
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.19.5/src/lib.rs:277:9
  22:     0x55cb94345c9c - <amethyst_window::system::EventsLoopSystem as shred::system::RunNow>::run_now::h88910af36d55f643
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst_window-0.15.3/src/system.rs:116:9
  23:     0x55cb94a136d9 - shred::dispatch::dispatcher::Dispatcher::dispatch_thread_local::h7cbde7b537b46e4a
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/shred-0.10.2/src/dispatch/dispatcher.rs:113:13
  24:     0x55cb94a1349e - shred::dispatch::dispatcher::Dispatcher::dispatch::ha68ff6dc80101173
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/shred-0.10.2/src/dispatch/dispatcher.rs:65:9
  25:     0x55cb9414942e - amethyst::game_data::GameData::update::h3aa99527bfafc632
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst-0.15.3/src/game_data.rs:47:13
  26:     0x55cb9414768c - <T as amethyst::state::State<amethyst::game_data::GameData,amethyst::state_event::StateEvent>>::update::hf7c34d8212bf3c54
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst-0.15.3/src/state.rs:345:9
  27:     0x55cb93e21a40 - amethyst::state::StateMachine<T,E>::update::h433a0eb30c8a08bf
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst-0.15.3/src/state.rs:447:21
  28:     0x55cb93f00bf4 - amethyst::app::CoreApplication<T,E,R>::advance_frame::h2ddcc8c7d3aef3c0
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst-0.15.3/src/app.rs:379:13
  29:     0x55cb93f00ea6 - amethyst::app::CoreApplication<T,E,R>::run::h52dcb6947c78c873
                               at /home/Matvey/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/amethyst-0.15.3/src/app.rs:243:13
  30:     0x55cb93f79f41 - amethyst::main::h3f8c426681afcb3e
                               at /home/Matvey/projects/amethyst/src/main.rs:32:5
  31:     0x55cb93f32c3b - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h05e72402c31adf19
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  32:     0x55cb93eb151e - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h58377dde04a8aa8e
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:134:18
  33:     0x55cb94009711 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h3fe9be8c31f346ba
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
  34:     0x55cb94b0833e - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::hee148dbc42d6d67d
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  35:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5f8a90d73360ad85
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  36:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panicking::try::h825d6a9433ebfecc
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  37:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panic::catch_unwind::h06de9052b9fcd12a
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  38:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h031af635de350c00
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  39:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panicking::try::do_call::haee4d1c4e889e5ae
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  40:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panicking::try::h3271bd5f3c59c034
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  41:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::panic::catch_unwind::h6b0df9b6b25a5fa1
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  42:     0x55cb94b0833e - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h9617a1e605205952
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  43:     0x55cb940096ea - std::rt::lang_start::he7c08fba2fb37b64
                               at /rustc/0599b6b931816ab46ab79072189075f543931cbd/library/std/src/rt.rs:165:17
  44:     0x55cb93f7a06e - main
  45:     0x7fac6f3a6790 - <unknown>
  46:     0x7fac6f3a684a - __libc_start_main
  47:     0x55cb93e1f5f5 - _start
  48:                0x0 - <unknown>
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Как это можно исправить?

Система: Arch Linux.

Версия rust: 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите использовать amethyst? Его разработка была прекращена в конце 2021 года. Я думаю вам лучше поискать другой движок.

Comment: @vessd, здравствуйте. Спасибо за совет. Тогда, можно уточнить, какой движок для rust вы посоветуете?